# How to make the width of header 100% all the time?

Tags: html, css, sass

Whenever I am testing with google chrome's dev tools for responsiveness, and when I am selecting Galaxy fold device or when I am shrinking the screen width via chrome dev tools , when the size goes below 300 x 655, the background of the header collapses. How to make it 100% width in all screen size?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #202063;
  color: gainsboro;
  ul {
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
  }
  main,
  header {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #202063;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: space-between;
  nav {
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      li {
        margin: 0 10px;
      }
      li:hover {
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
        padding-bottom: 4px;
      }
    }
  }
}

.text_center {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>MrSrv7</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h4 id="brand_text" class="text_center">MrSrv7</h4>
      <nav>
        <ul id="navlinks">
          <li>
            <a href="#about">
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact"> Contact </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#testimonials"> Testimonials </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create demo at jsfiddle or something like there and share here?

Comment: I added @ImBhavin95

Comment: I have run your code but it's showing me 100% width in every size.

Answer (score 0):

You need add: width=device-width in tag

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #202063;
            color: gainsboro;

            ul {
                li {
                    list-style-type: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit;
            }

            main,
            header {
                padding: 20px;
            }
        }

        header {
            display: flex;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #202063;
            font-weight: bold;
            justify-content: space-between;

            nav {
                ul {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;

                    li {
                        margin: 0 10px;
                    }

                    li:hover {
                        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
                        padding-bottom: 4px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .text_center {
            text-align: center !important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h4 id="brand_text" class="text_center">MrSrv7</h4>
            <nav>
                <ul id="navlinks">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about">
                            About
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact"> Contact </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#testimonials"> Testimonials </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can using CSS: @media (max-width: 300){ any your css width device<=300
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the min-width to 100%? I'm not sure what your nav bar looks like currently.

```
   header{
         min-width:100%
        }
```

Comment: tried and i even added !important to this rule

Comment: body{ margin:0} - Try this :)